# Sanitize sql input parameters using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework EDMX which automatically generates the needed functions i need for stored procedure executions as part of an auto generated class based on DBContext class.

for example, this is an auto generated function to execute stored procedure:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Company> GetCompanies(string companyName)
    {
        var companyNameParameter = companyName != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("CompanyName", companyName) :
            new ObjectParameter("CompanyName", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Company>("GetCompanies", companyNameParameter);
    }
```

Since i am using dynamic SQL inside some of the stored procedure, i would like to override ExecuteFunction and use "Custom ExecuteFunction" function to add some sanitize functions there which will loop over each parameter and sanitize it. i am wondering, maybe i can create a custom ObjectContext class and use it somehow?

How can i do it in a way that i will still be able to use the EDMX Entity framework auto generates functions?

i know that there is some solutions to sanitize the parameters inside the SP but i still want to learn how can i use custom ExecuteFunction function or custom ObjectContext together with EDMX.

Comment: you shouldn't *have* to sanitize it ... if the problem is that you're concatenating the values and using `EXEC (@sql)` - then: *don't do that* - you should be using `EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'{args definition}', @arg0, @arg1, ...` - which allows you to fully parameterize dynamic SQL; more context: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql

Comment: @MarcGravell i know that but i still want to learn how can i use custom ExecuteFunction function or custom ObjectContext together with EDMX.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i do it in a way that i will still be able to use the EDMX Entity framework auto generates functions?

Since the generated functions are virtual, you can override them in a subclass.

eg

```
public class MyDbContext2 : MyDbContext
{
    public override ObjectResult<Company> GetCompanies(string companyName)
    {
       Sanatize(companyname);
       return base.GetCompanies(companyName);
    }
//. . .
}
```

Comment: In that way, i need to do this to every function that needs to be sanitized in MyDBContext. Is there an option to override somehow the  ExecuteFunction function by inherit from ObjectContext?

Comment: AFAIK no.  And you only need to do this for the procedures where you are using dynamic SQL and not sanitizing the input parameters in the stored procedure itself.